# Prefill values in iframe form with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, widget

I am trying to prefill the values of an external widget that it is inserted in the page.

According to the widget's documentation, one can create manually a specific widget with prefilled values, but since I can have hundreds of possible values, that would be very time-consuming and not scalable.

Therefore, I am trying to make it with Javascript or jQuery.

Once the external widget is inserted, its html looks like this:

```
<ins class="bookingaff" ...>
    <iframe src="...>

        #document
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
            ...
            <form id="..." ...>
                ...
                <input class="searchbox__inp ..." type="search" id="b_destination" name="ss" value="" ...">

            </form>

        </html>

     </iframe>
</ins>
```

I tried several things, but nothing works. Here is an example:

```
<script>

  var widgetDOMs = document.getElementsByClassName('bookingaff');
  var widgetDOM = widgetDOMs[0]
  console.log('widgetDOM:', widgetDOM); //until here OK, element found. Console is showing the tree structure written above

  //with javascript
  var innerDoc = widgetDOM.getElementsByClassName('searchbox__inp');
  console.log('innerDoc:', innerDoc); // innerDoc: HTMLCollection []

  //with jQuery
  var innerDoc = $(widgetDOM).find('.searchbox__inp');
  console.log('innerDoc:', innerDoc); // length of innerDoc element is 0

  //once the elements inside the document widgetDOM can be accessed, I guess adding the value to the form would be straightforward...

</script>
```

No matter what I try, I do not manage to access any element inside the document inserted with the `iframe`. How can I do that?

Comment: `var widgetDOM = widgetDOMs[0].getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument`

Comment: @haim770 when I try this I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined`

Comment: Make sure your `.bookingaff` element is actually having an `<iframe>` element descendant

Comment: It does have an `<iframe>` descendant. The console log actually shows the `html` I posted in the question.